# Less verbose method of merging with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Say I want to merge two dataframes, df1 (consistent of columns 'a','b','c','z') and df2 consisting of columns('a','b','d','y'), together.  Columns 'a' and 'b' for both dataframes contain the same corresponding information.  Normally I would do the following to produce a new dataframe where 'c' and 'd' are assigned to corresponding 'a' and 'b':

```
relevant_columns1 = ['a','b','c']
relevant_columns2 = ['a','b','d']
df3 = pd.merge(df1[relevant_columns1], df2[relevant_columns2])
```

However, is there a less verbose way I could pass in this information through the merge function without having to put the column titles in a list format?  My object here is to produce a new dataframe, df3, that has columns 'a','b','c', and 'd'

Comment: You could do `df3=df1['a','b','c']` and `df4=df2['a','b','d']` and then `df3=pd.merge([df3,df4])`.  Not sure it's an improvement but you could do that.  ;-)

Comment: You could also just merge the whole thing and drop columns 'y' and 'z'.  Same pros and cons as unutbu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
pd.merge(df1, df2)[['a','b','c','d']]
```

---

By default `pd.merge` will merge based on all columns shared in common.

```
In [71]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape((5, 4)), columns=list('abcz'))

In [72]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape((5, 4)), columns=list('abdy'))

In [79]: pd.merge(df1, df2)
Out[79]: 
    a   b   c   z   d   y
0   0   1   2   3   2   3
1   4   5   6   7   6   7
2   8   9  10  11  10  11
3  12  13  14  15  14  15
4  16  17  18  19  18  19
```

You could then select just the columns that you desire:

```
In [78]: pd.merge(df1, df2)[['a','b','c','d']]
Out[78]: 
    a   b   c   d
0   0   1   2   2
1   4   5   6   6
2   8   9  10  10
3  12  13  14  14
4  16  17  18  18
```

So 
`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2)[['a','b','c','d']]` is less verbose, but it does create a larger temporary dataframe, so your method may be more memory-efficient, especially if there are a lot of irrelevant columns.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
df3 = pd.merge(list(df1), list(set(list(df2)) - set(list(df1))))
```